# Linked Table in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

Good morning I have the following query which has created a temp table, what I want is for this table to be permanent and whenever the other tables are updated then this table will be automatically updated to, I think there is such an easy way to do this but I have just forgotten.

Query linking 3 Tables

```
Select S.[Silks_Skey], MC.[MajorColour_Skey] 
from [dbo].[Silks] S 
inner join [dbo].[SubColour] SC on CHARINDEX(SC.[SubColour],S.[SilksName]) <> 0
inner join [dbo].[MajorColour] MC on SC.[MajorColour] = MC.[MajorColour]

UNION ALL

Select S.[Silks_Skey], MC.[MajorColour_Skey] 
from [dbo].[Silks] S 
inner join [dbo].[MajorColour] MC on CHARINDEX(MC.[MajorColour],S.[SilksName]) <> 0

ORDER BY S.[Silks_Skey]
```

Linked Table to be turned into a permanent table

```
Silks_Skey  MajorColour_Skey
1   7
1   8
2   2
2   8
2   9
3   4
3   5
```

Comment: Create a view containing this query.

Comment: Hi Bamar, I need a table is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Ho about using a View for this. Since you said, you want this query result to get updated when ever tables are updated. Make it as View.

Comment: Can you use a view within SSRS as a dataset?

Comment: I am not sure about this in SSRS. But, this should be possible in all DB

Comment: Hi Santhosh, the whole point of the query was to create a table which then can be used as part of a dataset to pass onto Report Buider.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW [silkColours]
AS
Select S.[Silks_Skey], MC.[MajorColour_Skey] 
from [dbo].[Silks] S 
inner join [dbo].[SubColour] SC on CHARINDEX(SC.[SubColour],S.[SilksName]) <> 0
inner join [dbo].[MajorColour] MC on SC.[MajorColour] = MC.[MajorColour]

UNION ALL

Select S.[Silks_Skey], MC.[MajorColour_Skey] 
from [dbo].[Silks] S 
inner join [dbo].[MajorColour] MC on CHARINDEX(MC.[MajorColour],S.[SilksName]) <> 0

ORDER BY S.[Silks_Skey]
```